# Oracle 11g on a hard disk

Tags: windows, oracle

Can I install Oracle 11g on a hard drive. Can I use this hard drive in another computer where 11 g is not installed and just play a bit with Oracle?

Comment: Why not just install it on that computer?

Comment: Cannot that is a live server, hence my manager wants me to create for him something like a hard drive which would have oracle installed in it. But i have no idea about this, because what I think is that oracle 11 g creates some temporary files in windows which wont allow this to happen. What do you think about this??

Comment: So you can't install Oracle, but you can put in random hard drives from your desktop machine? Your manager needs to provide you with a test/development server.

Comment: Can you please give me deep explanation on this.And one more thing by hard drive I meant an external hard drive

Comment: The deep explanation for this is that you're out of your depth and this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 2):

That's not possible. Oracle install creates several services, modifies the registry to include `oracle_home` path amogst others. Without these services running & none of the registry keys, the server won't start.

And if you have configured the data & log files to be on separate drives, then that's another whole different ballgame.

---

If you need to play with something, just use a Virtual Machine. [Oracle provides several VM appliances](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html) and that you can just download & start playing with. If you need your live data to work with, export the data, import it into the VM  & play to your hearts' content.

Comment: By playing i meant write queries and update database.